Slicing Graph by path
I have a Graph (generally not planar and without particular layout), and a simple path that connects two points of its boundary, as in the example shown below.
How to cut the Graph by the path ? Meaning, to get the separate graphs at each side of the path (including it each one).
I think identifying the vertices on each side and then keeping the relevant edges, but this identifications seems challenging.
   graphbase = GridGraph[{10, 10}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]; 
    zcoord[x_] := Exp[-(x - 10)^2] + 2*Exp[-(x - 5)^2] + 2*Exp[-(x - 15)^2]; 
     coordsmap = Thread[Array[#1 & , 
     Length[VertexList[graphbase]]] -> (Append[#1, zcoord[Tr[#1]]] & ) /@GraphEmbedding[graphbase]]; 
     graphinput = Graph[VertexList[graphbase], EdgeList[graphbase],VertexCoordinates -> coordsmap]; 
      cut = DeleteDuplicates[Join[FindShortestPath[graphinput, 2, 43],FindShortestPath[graphinput, 43, 48], FindShortestPath[graphinput, 48, 99]]]; 
       HighlightGraph[graphinput, PathGraph[cut]]


It has been suggested that this question is similar to this other one, however that one is not only fairly simpler but different, in the sense that there it is asked to obtain the connected components of a Graph after a single edge is deleted. Here no edge or edges are deleted, but the important property is that they are shared by both would-be connected subgraphs.

What does zcoord have to do with your problem?

Please provide definition for graph.

@Edmund Thank you. Please see edit.

@DavidG.Stork Thank you. Not much, I just want to stress the fact that the kind of graphs I am considering come from actual figures in 3d, and if projected into 2d the edges may be self-intersecting. Thus to avoid a possible solution that may not work if the edges self intersect.

Suppose your graph is a CompleteGraph[4], realized as a square and two diagonals. Suppose the boundary is a square, and the path is one of the diagonals. Then, what do you mean by "cutting"?

gr = GridGraph[{10, 10}];
AnnotationValue[gr, VertexCoordinates] = GraphEmbedding[gr];
path = {2, 3, 13, 23, 33, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 59, 69, 79, 89, 
   99};

HighlightGraph[gr, PathGraph[path]]
HighlightGraph[VertexDelete[gr, #], PathGraph[path]] & /@ 
 ConnectedComponents[VertexDelete[gr, path]]



